# Why doesn't Grafana show me the correct count?

Tags: statistics, grafana, graphite, statsd

I'm trying to do something in Grafana/Graphite which should be really easy, but has me baffled. I'd like to get the total by which a count has increased during the period I select in the top right corner of the Grafana UI.

Users of our site can import content from various sources, and every time they do an import, we increment a StatsD count. We include the source type in the StatsD path, so we can break out the numbers for each type of import in Grafana, as in this example.

[image]

Unfortunately, in this view of the graph Grafana is giving us crazy numbers. When we check them against another stats service we also use we see very different data. For example, the import Grafana shows as 96.9 in this screenshot, in our other system has a value of 4,466 over the last week. We're totally sure our other system is right and Grafana's number is wrong.

Can anyone suggest what we're doing wrong? We want a chart that'll give us the breakdown of number of imports of each type during the selected date range. Over 7 days, we'd expect the big green item to be 4,466, not 96.6. On a date range like 1 day, we'd expect it to be something like
629, because the count gets incremented by about that much per day.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to answer your question four years after it is helpful... The reason could be because grafana consolidates the datapoints based on the width of the graph. You can set the max data points to -1 on a query to get all datapoints returned.